# Can't unlock my phone after using DevicePolicyManager .lockNow()

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I come here cause i create an android app which switch off the screen (by locking it) with .lockNow().

This is my code :

```
btnToSleep.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            time = Integer.parseInt(timeBeforeSleep.getText().toString());

            m_handlerTask = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(time > 0){
                        Log.i("timeleft",""+time);
                        time--;
                    }else{
                        m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask); // cancel run
                        dpm.lockNow();

                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
                }
            };
            m_handlerTask.run();
        }
    });
```

This work but i can't unlock my phone after :( . If you know a way to solve it I will very happy :D. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into using the PowerManager to tell your device to go to sleep.  It should have the same effect as pressing the power button to turn off the screen.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep(long)

You will need to add the DEVICE_POWER permission to use it.

If you want an app to be able to actually enable the lock screen, I believe that has to be done through [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this method and I will be back :D

Comment: I had tried but android studio says to me that my DeviceAdminSample class can't be assignable to activity this is logical cause I don't extends it. I had follow the steps :(.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't played around with Device Admin much.  You may want to submit a new question about toggling the lock screen state  through Device Admin (i.e. enabling the lock screen when it's normally not locked on wake up) or adding a new one if it's not defined.